CSS text transparency effect through layer
I want to make text on website transparent in relation to div positioned under.
I have two divs - "content" and "overlay", which are placed on top of each other and overlap each other.


//I also use JS to transform the overlay after DOM loaded:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            var overlay = document.querySelector(".overlay");
            setTimeout(function() {
                overlay.style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
            }, 2000);
        });
.slide-container {
    position: relative;
}
.content, .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 100px;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    background-image: url(img.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
}
.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(23,30,32, .9);
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    transform: translateX(60vw);
    transition: ease 2s all;
    color: white;
}
    <div class="slide-container">
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="overlay">
            <h1>Some text</h1>
            <p>Some more text</p>
        </div>
    </div>



The text is only in "overlay" div. Is it possible to make text color the same as background that is currently under it's div?
Regardless of translateX of the overlay element, and also at the moment of transition, I want the text to always display the background underneath it.
The main problem is that there are 2 divs under each other, and mix-blend-mode isn't actually working for me. Setting the same, static background for text and using background-clip: text also doesn't solve the problem, because during the transition text has static background.
Here is exact desired effect example (Imgur).
